# How to add the library for OAuth

Tags: iphone

I am facing this error, what will be poosible reason for that error

```
ld: library not found for -lOAuth
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
Command /Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/usr/bin/gcc-4.2 failed with exit code 1
```

thanks for any help.

Comment: The first line tells you exactly what the error is.

Comment: i know this is because of that library, but i need to know how to solve that kind of error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

if you are using twitter+oAuth then you need to drag `libOAuth.a` lib in your project you are missing that.

you can find `libOAuth.a` in your sample code folder

Answer (score 0):

This Error occur when you use two file's with the same name, or you use, two  same name of variable into two different .m files. So check that out.

Answer (score 0):

When you miss one or more file, you will get this error. Check out for that missing file.